# c++, how to change the objects of the pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, reference

I am quite new to c++.

I was wondering if there was any way to have the pointer of a vector point to an array.

In my program, I have vector iterator objects that point to the first and last element of the vector, like this:

```
vector<int>::iterator vb = vec.begin();
vector<int>::iterator ve = vec.end();
```

and I have an array called 'result.'

I want to have 'vb' point to the first element of 'result', and 've' point to the last element of 'result.'

I've tried this:

```
vb = &result;
int resultLen = result.size();
ve = &(result+resultLen);
```

But I ended up with this error:

```
`error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘vb = & result’
```

I tried some variations such as:

```
*vb = &result;
int resultLen = result.size();
*ve = &(result+resultLen);
```

It didn't work either.

Any help will be appreciated, and thank you in advance!!

=============================================================================
**UPDATE**. This is a simple version of the program I am trying to write.

```
vector<int>::iterator vb = vec1.begin(); 
vector<int>::iterator ve = vec1.end();

int arr = {1,2,3}
int result [10];

while (True) {
    subtraction (vb, ve, arr, arr+5, result); 
// let's say the vector has {1,2,3,4,5}. I am subtracting array from vector like this: 12345 - 123 until it becomes less than 123. 
        /*I now need to update the vector from which I am subtracting the array to the result array.*/
        vb = &result; //points to the first element of array
        int resultLen = result.size();
        ve = &result+resultLen; //points to the last element of array
    }
```

Updating the vector is where I am having a trouble with.

Comment: You're trying to get vector iterators to somehow "point into" an ordinary array?

Comment: No, that makes no sense at all. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The result of some computations gets stored in the array, 'result,' and 'vb' and 've' are inputs to the computations in a loop. I need to update 'vb' and 've' at each run. I hope I am making myself clear on this.

Comment: Not really. Please try and post a short example of exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay. Will do. I could post chunk of my code, but that won't really help...I would have to post the entire program. give me a min.

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope I've made myself more clear now.

Comment: can you post subtraction  function?

Comment: That's very long. But yes, I will.

Comment: I posted it, but I don't think that'd help you understand better. I know that's a very stupid code, but there is a reason behind it. You'd have to bear that with me. Sorry.

Comment: @Nayana Why don't you make `result` vector?

Comment: @banarun I can't. I has to be an array. It's hard to explain... is there a way to handle it without making 'result' vector?

Comment: Do not use `iterator` use array index to traverse the array

Comment: @banarun Okay. Then, can I do vec1[0] = &result; and vec1[the last index] = &result+resultLen; ??

Comment: No, that is not how you access the elements of an array. use `result[0], result[1],....result[n-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Because `result` is not a vector. You cannot assign iterator of vector to an array. You can only assign it to an `int` type vector.

Comment: I can see that what I am trying to do is illegal, I was asking if there was a workaround to accomplish this. The result of some computations gets stored in the array, 'result,' and 'vb' and 've' are inputs to the computations in a loop. I need to update 'vb' and 've' at each run. I hope I am making myself clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

It does possible, here is your example code with my simplification:

```
std::vector<int> vec1;

vec1.push_back(1);
vec1.push_back(2);
vec1.push_back(3);

std::vector<int>::iterator vb = vec1.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator ve = vec1.end();

int result[] = {3,2,1};
*vb = *result; //points to the first element of array
int resultLen = sizeof(result)/sizeof(result[0]);
*ve = *(result+resultLen-1); //points to the last element of array

std::cout<<vec1[0]<< " " <<vec1[1] << " " <<vec1[2] << " " <<vec1[3];
```

the result is:

```
3 2 3 1
```

remember you are accessing iterator::end, which mean past the last value